# Does a Pokémon get more EV after level 100 in Gen I and II?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

Does a Pokémon get more EV after level 100 in Gen I and II? I'm playing both Red and Crystal on my original Game Boy Color, and leveling up my team, after they reach level 100 (**even if i trade one Pokémon to the other game**) will still get more EV (Effort Values) after it gets to level 100?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to deposit your Pokémon in a box and withdraw them back in order for their stats to change.

Comment: But does that work with every reset? do the Pokemon still have a limit for their 'EVs'? or can they reach stats like, 999?

Comment: Of course their EVs still have a cap. That doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks! And lastly, is there any way to know when my Pokemon reached max EV on Gen I or II games?

Comment: That is a different question, which I won't answer here.